# Can someone fool me with their location on 'Find my iPhone'?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, find-my-iphone, find-my-friends

Can someone fake location in iphone?

Comment: Yes, you can "unjailbreak" a phone, but it's not something you'd want to do on a daily basis. However, it's also possible to hide Cydia on a Jailbroken device, or take other steps to make your phone appear unjailbroken.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the dysfunctional relationship the OP is in cannot be solved by technology. Perhaps this question should be posted on Interpersonal SE.

Comment: @IconDaemon Its not off topic. The core question is on topic it just needs to be edited to eliminate the excess info.

Comment: @Ritesh This depends on so many factors it's impossible to answer—your device, your iOS version, method used, etc. But it would be MUCH easier to just hide the Jailbreak. And yes, Find My iPhone works on Jailbroken devices.

Comment: @Ritesh There may be a clever way I'm overlooking, but I can't think of a method that couldn't be hidden by a Jailbreak user. Settings → "Erase All Content and Settings" will brick a Jailbroken device (requiring an iTunes restore), but you _really_ don't want to do that to someone else's phone.

Answer (score 3):

> the guy ... knows how to google things very well.

Which is not the same as being a competent software engineer, and that's what you will need to be to send false info to Apple's location services.

> Sometimes I see her call log and see calls from her parents even when her find my iPhone location is at home and her parents are at home.

Means nothing. I know several people who call others in the same house. Easier than yelling down the hallway or to the back yard.*

The easiest way to appear to be elsewhere is to get a second device. An iPod will work just fine. Set it up with the same Apple ID and select it in any of the location services apps. That works for Find My Friends, does not work for Find My Phone. Since you said "Find my Phone" you are either using the wrong term, she has a phone you own, or you have access to her Apple ID?

Sounds like you need to do some private detective work. Just drive over to where she is and see if she is there.

- Funny of the Day:
  Girl is watching a movie with boyfriend. Hears incoming text on the phone, which she left in the kitchen. Gets up, goes to phone which reads "bring more chips back" sent by boyfriend who is still on the couch.

Comment: I would have upvoted this answer if it contained only the third (non-quoted) paragraph. Everything else is extraneous/off-topic.

Comment: I liked the joke... :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is perfectly possible to spoof the location of an iPhone. In fact Apple actually provide a mechanism for developers to do just that.

It involves editing the .plist fils got maps and a quick search will provide multiple tutorials. If I’d however not fir the faint hearted and  I doubt anyone would go to the trouble when switching off location services would be just as effective in hiding their location